# Error after adding second datatable control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I use a datalist control populated from a DataTable to display images in an application. Now I need to modify this to show two lists of images that come from different DataTables. So added a second DataList and coded for a second DataTable.

I receive an error:

> The Connection String Property has not been initialized.

Code for the DataTable controls, second one (`edt`) is generating the error:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (Conn)
{
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QuestionID, Images2.ImageID, ImageFile, ImageContent, ImageName, SEQ_NUM from qimages join Images2 on qimages.imageid = images2.imageid where QuestionID = @QuestionID", Conn);
    ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
    ad.Fill(dt);
}
dlImages.DataSource = dt;
dlImages.DataBind();

DataTable edt = new DataTable();
using (Conn)
{
    SqlDataAdapter ed = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QuestionID, Images2.ImageID, ImageFile, ImageContent, ImageName, SEQ_NUM from eimages join EditedImages on eimages.imageid = editedimages.imageid where QuestionID = @QuestionID", Conn);
    ed.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
    ed.Fill(edt);
}
EditImages.DataSource = edt;
EditImages.DataBind();
```

Tried changing the second control to use its own connection string as suggested. Below is the new code for the second datatable, which is still throwing the same not initialized error:

```
string Constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection Conn2 = new SqlConnection(Constr);
            DataTable edt = new DataTable();
            using (Conn2)
            {
                SqlDataAdapter ed = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QuestionID, EditImages.ImageID, ImageFile, ImageContent, ImageName, SEQ_NUM from eimages join EditImages on eimages.imageid = editimages.imageid where QuestionID = @QuestionID", Conn);
                ed.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
                ed.Fill(edt);
            }
            EditImages.DataSource = edt;
            EditImages.DataBind();
```

Comment: If the error says the connection string property hasn't been initialized, it's probably a good idea to show how you're initializing the connection string in your question. Please read over [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as your question lacks the Complete principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're disposing of the connection when you're done with it (that's what the using block is for). Either do all your database interaction inside one using block, or create a second connection with the same connection string. Here's an example of doing it within the same using block.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataTable edt = new DataTable();

using (Conn)
{
    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QuestionID, Images2.ImageID, ImageFile, ImageContent, ImageName, SEQ_NUM from qimages join Images2 on qimages.imageid = images2.imageid where QuestionID = @QuestionID", Conn);
    ad.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
    ad.Fill(dt);
    SqlDataAdapter ed = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QuestionID, Images2.ImageID, ImageFile, ImageContent, ImageName, SEQ_NUM from eimages join EditedImages on eimages.imageid = editedimages.imageid where QuestionID = @QuestionID", Conn);
    ed.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("QuestionID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request["Id"]);
    ed.Fill(edt);
}

dlImages.DataSource = dt;
dlImages.DataBind();
EditImages.DataSource = edt;
EditImages.DataBind();
```

You've got a lot of repeated code here, you might think of refactoring it into a method. You've also got database access logic mix into your Web Forms code behind, which is very messy. All your database logic should be abstracted out into a separate data access layer.

Comment: Thanks, this took care of the issue. I know my code is far from optimal here. When I have tried to setup and use a separate data access layer I can't seem to get it to work... so stuck having to do this in order to have a functioning application.

Comment: @BrentOliver It's pretty simple to set up a data access layer. Create a new class. Add functions in it that talk to the database, and do all your data access through that layer. Avoid using data tables, pass objects around through strongly typed model objects. I've created an [example project here](https://github.com/mason-mcglothlin/FancyStoreDemo) that shows using multiple data layers that can be swapped out at will in an application.

Comment: one of the issues I had with the DAL was in using views. For displaying some data I had views, and could not get them to work using classes. I did start with that, but diverged into using stored procedures and connection strings as I had to get this working,,, and could work with those entities.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when a datasource attempts to bind to data, but cannot because can't find the connection string.

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[nameOfConnectionString].ConnectionString;
```

Further more, use this: `using(SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection("......"))` when you want to make changes in database or retrieve data.

**Keeping a global instance of a connection object is a bad practice because you risk to loose control on the lifetime of that instance.**

Comment: I don't understand why it would do that as the connection string "Conn" worked just fine prior to adding the second datatable control, which uses the same Conn connection string.

Comment: I have used this connection string for months on this same page. The only change is the second datatable control in my question. I know the connection string works, but for some reason it does not like the second datatable control. Do I have to do something to "close" the first datatable before I can open a second? I know the issue is not that the connection string itself is invalid.

Comment: @BrentOliver You're disposing of the connection when you're done with it (that's what the using block is for). Either do all your database interaction inside one `using` block, or create a second connection with the same connection string.

Comment: @mason, Exactly. `Using` calls  `Dispose()` after the `using`-block is left,